# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2) in C when trying to change value in string

Tags: c, pointers, runtime-error

This code throws the EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error when trying to set `t[j]`to `t[j+1]` and i dont understand why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int strclean(char *t){
    int tmp2 = 0;
    if(t == NULL){
        return -1;
    }
    int i = 0;
    while(t[i] != NULL) {
        if (isprint(t[i]) == 0 || isspace(t[i])) {
            tmp2++;
            for(int j = i; t[j]!=NULL;j++){
                t[j] = t[j+1];               //throws error
            }
            i--;
        }
        printf("%c\n", t[i]);
        i++;
    }
    t[i] = "\0";
    return tmp2;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", strclean("fg h ear p\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: Literal strings are effectively *read-only* in C. Attempting to modify a literal string leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Also note that `NULL` is the null *pointer*, not the string null terminator. The null terminator is the character `'\0'`. And that `"\0"` is very different from `'\0'`.

Comment: thank you! I was so confused as to what was wrong, since all I got when i googled this were situations where the memory was not properly allocated.

Comment: When in your `for` loop `t[j]` will be pointing to the last `t` element, `t[j] != NULL` is true, but `t[j+1]` are out of `t` bounds, so you are reading out of `t`.